# php - recursive function in hierarchy table

Tags: php, recursion, yii2, infinite-loop

I'm trying from table with departments hierarchy, get all childs from specific father department.

**table**

```
id | id_department | id_department_manager
 1         15              12
 2          4              15
 3         33              15
 4         27              33
 5         12              12
```

**recursive function**

```
function recursive (array $elements) {

   $arr = $elements;

   foreach ($arr as $value) {
      $departments = DepartmenstDependencies::find()->where(['id_department_manager' => $value])->all();
   }

   foreach ($departments as $department) {
       $arr[] = $department->id_department;
       $arr = recursive($arr);
   }

   return $arr;
}

recursive([12]);
```

the goal is for example when i call `recursive([15])` correct return is `Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 4 [2] => 33 [3] => 27 )`  it's ok.

but when i call `recursive([12])` the correct output is `Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 15 [2] => 4 [3] => 33 [4] => 27 )`  but i get infinite loop, this is because the last line in table `5, 12, 12` but how i advoid this? this recursive function is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice quiz. I suppose you don't want the returned array to contain duplicates. Replace

```
foreach ($departments as $department) {
    $arr[] = $department->id_department;
    $arr = recursive($arr);
}
```

with

```
foreach ($departments as $department) {
    if (!in_array($department->id_department, $arr)) {
        $arr[] = $department->id_department;
        $arr = recursive($arr);
    }
}
```